# Make an autoplaying embedded YouTube video pop up in the middle of the screen on button click

Tags: button, video, popup, embed, autoplay

This is going to sound a little silly, but I have a very basic "Rickroll button" on my site that opens a link to Rick Astley's "Never gonna give you up".

It works fine as is but the only issue is that the video opens on YouTube's website where it'll often play an ad before the video which really lessens the blow of the Rickroll.

I was just wondering if it's possible for me to change the button into opening a div that could autoplay the video? I've looked around on here for similar code though it wasn't specifically what I'm looking for.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ'">
 push for a surprise!
</button>
```